# replaceAll() method removes digits, but adds blank token

Tags: java, arraylist, tokenize, replaceall

I have a Java assignment (taken from Programming Pearls) where I have to take input from a text file (using Scanner and FileReader objects), remove all punctuation and numbers and then create an ArrayList with each word sorted alphabetically in ascending order. Then, I have to printout each word followed by a number with the number of repetitions (occurences) of the word, and remove the duplicates.

My problem is that the replaceAll() method I am using does remove everything as expected, but with one unexpected consequence. The number in my text is converted into a blank token (word), which is then inserted into my ArrayList. When I inspect the ArrayList fields, it shows as "".

I've tried all sorts of different regular expressions, with the same result. Anyone has an idea why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Here's is the code excerpt:
dictionary is the ArrayList object and inFile the Scanner object.

```
dictionary.add(inFile.next().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-z]", "").trim());
```

Many thanks

---

Sorry, guys. My bad. yes, it should be like this a-zA-Z. But nothing changes. Here's the code and the output:

```
     public class Dictionary
        { 
            private List <String> dictionary;
            private Scanner inFile; 


            public Dictionary() 
    {

                this.dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();

            } 

            public void parseText ()
    {             
       inFile = new Scanner (new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Ovid.txt"));


        while (inFile.hasNext())                    
                  dictionary.add(inFile.next().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").trim());

Collections.sort(dictionary);
}
```

And here's the output (from print statement):

dictiona1.parseText(); 
in 
the 
cool 
cool 
breeze 
of 
the 
evening 
the
nightingale 
sang

sweet
songs

As you can see, after "sang" there is a blank line. In the unparsed text there is a number there ("...sang 17 sweet songs"). The same is confirmed when I inspect the ArrayList.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share a fuller snippet? It's quite hard to address this without context.

Comment: Additionally, a sample input would be appreciated.

Comment: Character case matters: `A-z` should be `A-Z`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: ^^ `A-z` is a big range (65-122) which includes the characters `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_\`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of your code. The `replaceAll(regex, "")` you are using says that replace every occurring of non-a-z word with a empty `String` "". And then add that empty String to the `List`.
You can avoid this writing of empty `String` while the time of adding List's values.
Break your while code(which you should always, as per best practices) and while adding values to List, put a check such that only non-null value will be inserted to `List`.

```
String next = inFile.next().toLowerCase();
String replaced = next.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").trim();
if(!replaced.equals("")){
       dictionary.add(replaced);        
}
```

I cannot make any guess for the newline you are getting after sang, until you provide the input String you are using.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this is the expected behaviour of my programme. I thought that the default delimiter pattern is whitespace. If that's the problem, then maybe I should use a different regex.

Comment: I found the correct regex: "[^a-zA-Z]*\\s+[^a-zA-Z]*". It now works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Yes the default delimiter is whitespace. For explaining you, lets take assume you passed "Hello my name is 12 puspender". Now scanner will pick this String and creates String tokens based on whitespaces, i.e "hello" "my" "name" "is" "12" "puspender". Now you are replacing all digits-word with empty space, but notice you are just converting a String to an empty String(not deleting the string). And then you add those tokens to an arraylist(along with a token which is empty string). Upvote if you understood the concept.